# React Functional component with parameter reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React functional component Users, which takes a parameter, a URL, which was received by an API call.I want to use this parameter to fetch some data, however when reloading on that page it renders nothing because the parameter is undefined. It also gives an error. It works however when I switch between pages, because then the URL is loaded.

My code:

App.js

```
function App() {
  const [structure, setStructure] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        // API CALL
        fetchStructure().then((result) => setStructure(result));
    }, []); 

  // removed some parts of the layout
  return (
          <div className="bodydiv">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/users" ><Users url={structure.users} /></Route>
            <Route path="/cars"><Cars url={structure.cars} /></Route>
            <Route path="/offers" ><Offers url={structure.offers} /></Route>
          </Switch>
          </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Users.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import {fetchUsers} from '../Api';


function Users(props) {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    

    useEffect(() => {
        //API CALL
        fetchUsers(props.url).then((result) => setUsers(result));
    }, []);


    return (
        <div>
            {(users || []).map((user) => (
                <Typography variant="h3" gutterBottom >{user.name}</Typography>                
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Users;
```

How can the function "wait" for the props.url to be loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add dependecies to your `useEffect` like this

```
function Users(props) {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    

    useEffect(() => {
        //API CALL
        fetchUsers(props.url).then((result) => setUsers(result));
    }, [props.url]);

.....
```

So when props.url changes the `useEffect` will be called again, in your case it is called only once. And it is when you don't have a link yet. You can read about useEffect more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)